# confused about using WCF services

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

There is one WCF service ServiceOne. All it does is implements some functions, let's say int Add(int a, int b);

When I use this service in another project like this :

```
ServiceOneClient client = new ServiceOneClient();
int result = client.Add(10,10);
```

and it works fine.

But now I have to create another service ServiceTwo that simply implements ServiceOne functionality like this

```
int ServiceTwoAddMethod(int a, int b)
{
    return new ServiceOneClient().Add(a, b);
}
```

And I think that everything should work fine. But somehow when I add reference to ServiceTwo to the third project, 
this code of line

```
new ServiceTwoClient().Add(10, 10)
```

doesn't return what I want to see(20).

Please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't think there is enough information to give you an answer.

Comment: What is being returned from the ServiceTwoClient.Add method?

Comment: Do you add References, or Service References?

Comment: I have no idea why this question has received an upvote, it is unclear and at best, not possible to answer with the information provided.

Answer (score 1):

ensure that the *third project* has a *service reference* to **Service2** but also that it has *project* references to **Service1** and **Service2** (assuming all are in the same *solution*)

EDIT: when i say **Service1** and **Service2** i mean of course the *service contract class libraries* for each service.  i assume of course that you have a project for your service contracts and another for the actual service implementation